# How to get a stuck Chiclet key unstuck?

Tags: keyboard, laptop-repair, ultrabook

I have a Samsung NP9003XC-A01US and it has low-profile, island-type Chiclet keys. However, my control key is stuck on the bottom half (from the top view). It still presses down on the top half and if I press firmly, it registers the hit.

I saw some tutorials on getting keys unstuck, but they all refer to the type that is in older Dell and HP laptops, where one can easily separate the key with a screw-driver because the base is exposed.

Compressed air did not work.

Any advice?

I'm planning to try to lift up the key (with a knife or toothpick) a little bit and spray compressed air again. If unsuccessful, I will call Samsung and ask them if the keys are removable. If so, I will remove the key and clean the insides, then replace the key. I am not optimistic that any of this will work, so if you have any suggestions, please post them.

Comment: you mean the keyboard is like sony's ? exact laptop model?

Comment: NP900X3C-A01US  i tried compressed air, didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the keys are not user-removable. However, my wife used a reshaped staple to remove a small piece of plastic that was trapped under the key.